# Can I use my own database to authenticate with Auth0?

Tags: authentication, auth0

Can I use my own database to authenticate with Auth0? somebody has been use Auth0 like this?

I try to follow the steps to configurate, but I don't found were to put a connection to my database or something like this.

Comment: See https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/database-connections/custom-db/create-db-connection. It's available with Professional and Enterprise plans.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to *reactjs* or *next*. Please remove these tags.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say, I want to do it on nextjs